# Jquery png problem in IE

Tags: jquery, png, fadein

If you view this in IE7 or 8 you will see that the background, when fading in is black, then it rapidly disappoears. Is there a fix for this?

http://nettuts.s3.cdn.plus.org/234_tooltip/Demo/index.html

Many thanks in advance!
C

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look at your source, and I can't really say for sure. The code looks sound enough.

I'm guessing the backgound of that area is black with an opacity set (hard to tell exactly from the source I'm viewing) Can you include more details in your original post? Post your relevant CSS and plugin code - it doesn't appear too big, so there's no hard im this.

Can you slow it down, and make the drop bigger (temporarily) so its easier to see what's going on. I would also see if the same effect is apparent with jQuery 1.3.2. (you are currently using 1.3.1)

Another thing to try, is to block the animation, so it pops up in the start-of-animation position. What does it look like then?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2009/2/17/Fading-a-24bit-transparent-PNG-in-IE7

Because you're trying to fade-in a PNG with alpha-transparency.

Found via https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1792631/list